# VLC or MXPLAYER can not play a http url that has cookie authentication

Tags: python, video, cookies, proxy, vlc

when i use vlc to play a http url:

[http://cdn47.my.mail.ru/v/52916332.mp4?sign=04809eaa0476ef4937490d691cfe48a947b963b0&slave[]=s%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A5010%2F52916332-v.mp4&p=f&expire_at=1426798800&touch=1423155670](http://cdn47.my.mail.ru/v/52916332.mp4?sign=04809eaa0476ef4937490d691cfe48a947b963b0&slave%5B%5D=s%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A5010%2F52916332-v.mp4&p=f&expire_at=1426798800&touch=1423155670)

403 error has happend,but when i use a python script open the url with a cookies,i can download the video.

this is the cookies:
video_key = ff1f725ddbb12648d434d850dd8c22aecda13371.

you can find the cookies at this page:
http://videoapi.my.mail.ru/videos/mail/marika_131313/_myvideo/10.json?t=-1955407141

Answer (score 0):

Since the video players are separate applications from the browser, it would make sense that they can only use information given by said browser. Since they only give a URL, and no cookies, it would make sense why the media player doesn't have them. It's a natural state. 
My question in return is, why are they using cookies to identify the media desired? What if the user wanted to download or play multiple files?